# Measure of probability of obtaining a certain $\chi^2$ given the number of trials

Tags: probability, chi-squared-test, random-variable

I am calculating an equation with several random components a large number of times, and in order to select my final answer I choose that with the minimum value for $\chi^2$.

I am hoping to find some way to decide how probable it is that I should end up with this value of $\chi^2_{min}$, to take into account the number of trials used. Initially I thought this was correct:

$Probability =  \frac{e^{-\chi^2_{min}}}{\sum_i^{N_{trials}}e^{-\chi^2_{i}}}$

So essentially the probability is the exponential of the lowest calculated $\chi^2$, divided by the sum of all calculated exp($-\chi^2$) values. This seems reasonable in some sense, because if there are a range of results with a low value for $\chi^2$ (as would be the case for a large number of trials) then the numerator would tend toward 1 whilst the demonimantor would grow with the trial number, making the overall probability that I select the best answer smaller. It doesn't really do what I would like it to do, however: in the exteme example where I have only 1 trial then this would always evaluate to '1', irrespective of the quality of the answer.

In my equation I have several Gaussian random variables, and what I would really like is to have some measure of how 'far' a result is in terms of the means of these Gaussians, and include this in how I define the 'probability'. ie: if I have two results with similar $\chi^2$ but the random components of one are all very close to the means and the other a multiple $\sigma$ away, then I would select the first as the 'more probable' result.

Is there any technique that exists to do something like this?

Hopefully this is clear enough to comprehend - I'm pretty unsure of how next to proceed and any suggestions would be very welcome.

**Editing to add a new idea:**

I'm thinking of what I could do to take all of these elements into account is to do something like:

$Probability =  \frac{e^{-\chi^2_{min}} \times e^{-a} \times e^{-b}}{\sum_i^{N_{trials}}e^{-\chi^2_{i}} \times e^{-a} \times e^{-b}}$

where $a$ and $b$ (in $e^{-a}$ and $e^{-b}$) represent the distance from the mean of the Gaussian variables.

Comment: What is $\chi^2$?

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer will clear things up, but I just calculate the $\chi^2$ per trial based on $(x-\bar{x})/\sigma)^2$, where $x$ is the result, $\bar{x}$ the expected result and $\sigma$ is the uncertainty.